# Python Scrapy - common way to configure scrapers

Tags: python, scrapy, initialization, web-crawler

Python framework Scrapy works pretty well but I can not figure out how to configure spiders at runtime. Seems that all configuration should me made "statically" which is not handy. Awful design or I missed something?

For example I have a spider that requires difficult initialization routine.
I use my own scripts to obtain HTTP headers for crawling (cookies, user-agent etc.) - as it were logged-in user.
This takes one-two minute. After that these headers should be applied to all requests.

Right now I do this in `__init__` method of the spider. But I can not set up `User-Agent` from the constructor of the spider. `custom_settings` must be set up as class variable. Therefore I have to use middleware to set up user agent for each request. This is an ugly solution.

Do we have some common pattern to init spiders - some kind of `spider factory` ? Smth like this:

```
class SpiderConfigurator:

    def __init__():
        ...


    def configureSpider(spider, environment):
        ...
        spider.setMyCustomSettings(arg1, arg2)
        ...
        environment.setMyCustomSettings(argName1, argValue1)
        environment.setMyCustomSettings('User-Agent', 'my value')
```

Comment: Can you provide a short code example of what you're doing and what you'd like to do instead?

Comment: Have you checked [Run Scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) ?

Comment: @paultrmbrth Yes, seems this is what I need! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy allows to lounch crawling from the script: [Run Scrapy from script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) Thanks to @paultrmbrth for this hint

But we can not init spider - we just pass spider class to `Crawler` instance and then crawler instantiates the object. What we can do - pass parameters for our spider`s constructor. Smth like this:

```
os.chdir(scrapyDir)
projectSettings = get_project_settings()
crawlerProcess = CrawlerProcess(projectSettings)
crawlerProcess.crawl(SpiderCls,
                     argumentName1=argumentValue1,
                     argumentName2=argumentValue2)
```

Arguments `argumentName1` and `argumentName2` will be passed to the spider`s constructor.